# Java: an object of what type is produced if the class literal is applied to the primitive type?

Tags: java, class, generics, primitive-types

From what I know, there is a feature in Java called a class literal, which, applied to a type name, causes JVM to produce an object of type `Class<?>`, which is a generic class. More specifically, the following construct is correct:

```
Class<type> o = type.class;
```

where `type` is a name of any type available for use.

What confuses me is a combination of two facts. The first, that the class literal may be used with the primitive types as well, i.e. a construct like `int.class` is perfectly valid. And the second, that one's not allowed to use primitive types to parameterize generics, which means that a construct like `Class<int> c;` won't compile.

Given all the above, what type is used as the `Class` type parameter in the `Class<?> c = int.class;` statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simply a `Class<Integer>`.

```
Class<Integer> o = int.class;
```

Even if you used the primitive type Class representation, it's still a `Class<Integer>`:

```
Class<Integer> o = Integer.TYPE;
```

Comment: Okay, then a different, but a totally related question: how does Java distinguish between methods using primitive types and their respective wrapper classes when using `Class.getMethod`?

Comment: There is `Class#isPrimitive`. Integer.TYPE will return true there, whereas Integer.class will not.