# Why int.class argument required with getConstructor reflection api?

Tags: java, reflection

`Class` instance gets created in a per-type constant pool, when particular class(`X`) gets loaded.

`javac` compiles this syntax `int.class` to point to object that `Integer.TYPE` points to.

Below code, get access to parameterise(`int`) constructor of `class X`.

```
Class c = X.class;
Constructor cons = c.getConstructor(int.class);
cons.newInstance(10);
```

In the above code, I did not understand the role of `int.class` argument, under the hood.

Why `getConstructor` not designed to accept `String` type argument "int"  instead of   `int.class`? argument of `Class.forName()` is one example.

Comment: please read question again

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: an object of what type is produced if the class literal is applied to the primitive type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688157/java-an-object-of-what-type-is-produced-if-the-class-literal-is-applied-to-the)

Comment: The code searches for a constructor in ``class X`` with one parameter of type ``int``. The "class" ``Integer.TYPE`` refers to the primitive integer here...

Comment: Why do we need class literal syntax as argument? String "int" argument would not suffice??

Comment: @overexchange Because java developers felt like reusing the ``class`` keyword at this point. Taking a more abstract perspective, ``class`` stands for a ``type`` - which includes primitives (for reflection uses, ``void`` is also considered a type)

Comment: p.s.: You may take a look at the documentation of ``java.lang.Class#isPrimitive()``

Comment: Is the question, why have `int.class` as the argument and not `int`? I suspect the designers felt adding `.class` to the end made it clearer that this was a type literal rather than a cast missing a bracket or a variable which had been mistyped.

Comment: Err, this question is nonsense. `int` would be a ***syntax error.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `Class` is a type dedicated to a certain purpose. There are a lot of classes, whose instances we could simply replace by a `String` and it would work if we accept a bit of ambiguity and possibly a performance loss. E.g. why use numbers instead of `String`s containing their representation, or why use `enum`s instead of their names? So having an instance of the dedicated type ensures that the creating, lookup, parsing or whatever action is required to get that instance has already successfully performed.

So having a `Class` object representing `int.class`, you known that you are referring to an existing type, something you can’t say about the `String` `"int"`. A `String` parameter doesn’t necessarily refer to an existing type— it doesn’t even have to contain a valid name. And if you lookup a constructor having two `int` arguments, passing `"int", "int"` would imply to make the entire work of verifying the correctness and looking up the appropriate type twice. And so on…

And, since the restrictions of the Java programming language do not apply in the JVM, a `String` is ambiguous. It’s not clear whether `"int"` refers to a `class` named `int` or the primitive type `int`. Note that when you call `loadClass("int")` on a `ClassLoader`, it is always assumed that you are referring to a `class` named `int` as that method is not appropriate to look up primitive types. That’s the reason why `int.class` gets compiled to an access to `Integer.TYPE`, as primitive types can’t be looked up the same way as reference types.

Further, as already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205402/when-does-object-pointed-by-example-class-come-into-existence#comment50489815_31206292), a name is ambiguous at runtime as there can be multiple classes having the same name, being defined by different `ClassLoader`s.

See [JVMS §5.3 “Creation and Loading”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3):

> At run time, a class or interface is determined not by its name alone, but by a pair: its binary name ([§4.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.2.1)) and its defining class loader.

And also [JLS §12.2 “Loading of Classes and Interfaces”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2)

> Well-behaved class loaders maintain these properties:
>
> - Given the same name, a good class loader should always return the same class object.
> - If a class loader L1 delegates loading of a class C to another loader L2, then for any type T that occurs as the direct superclass or a direct superinterface of C, or as the type of a field in C, or as the type of a formal parameter of a method or constructor in C, or as a return type of a method in C, L1 and L2 should return the same Class object.
>
> A malicious class loader could violate these properties. However, it could not undermine the security of the type system, because the Java Virtual Machine guards against this.

Answer (score 1):

`int.class` instead of `Integer.TYPE` is syntactic sugar the java compiler substitutes. A `Class` object is briefly said, an object holding meta information about a code-internal structure. But if we take a more abstract view at this, we can reuse that class to represent `types`: `primitive`s, `interface`s, and even `void` - which isn't a type but rather an identifier for methods with **no** *return value*. This reuse of `Class` has quite some advanges as in your example; consider following code:

```
public class X {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        X myX = X.class.getConstructor().newInstance();
        X myBigX = X.class.getConstructor(Integer.class).newInstance(0xCEED);
        X mySmallX = X.class.getConstructor(int.class).newInstance(10);
    }

    public X() {
        System.out.println("parameterless constructor called");
    }

    public X(Integer bigInteger) {
        System.out.println("object integer constructor called");
    }

    public X(int smallInteger) {
        System.out.println("primitive integer constructor called");
    }
}
```

If the reflection API developers had introduced for each method that takes a `Class` object as type identificator had to introduce a second one which handles types which are not exactly `class`es that would create unnecessary code duplication and unflexibility. Now, why had they decided to append `.class` to primitive type keywords to refer to ther respective `Class` pointers? As some people already stated, leaving away that part would lead to further confusion and syntax errors. As it is, the suffix is just continuing the pattern of writing a hard coded type.